# Casting the LHS

Tags: vb.net, string, operators, concatenation

OK. Now this one is interesting. Haven't ever come across this before. How do I use Concat-Assign operator (`&=`) in the following case?

```
Session("MyKey") &= "some string" 'Option Strict prohibits operands of type Object and String
```

Looks like I can't even cast the LHS to String:

```
DirectCast(Session("MyKey"), String) &= "some string" 'Cannot assign becuz LHS is a value
```

I can't even seem to do this:

```
Dim s as String = Session("MyKey").ToString()
s &= "some string" 's is a new animal. Doesn't affect Session("MyKey")
```

I know it can easily be done by using simple `Session("MyKey") = Session("MyKey").ToString() & "some string"` but just want to ensure I'm not missing something really basic.

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything ridiculously basic. Session variables are treated just like any other variables of type Object. You can't use operators like DirectCast or ToString on the target of an assignment (i.e. on the left hand side of your assignment statement). Concatenate the string that you wish to assign into a string variable (or a string builder) and assign the result to your session variable.

```
Dim str As String = ""
If IsNothing(Session("MyKey")) = False Then str = Session("MyKey").ToString
str &= "some string"
Session("MyKey") = str
```